# compile python class with numba

Tags: python, numba, jit

I am using the `numba.jitclass()` decorator to compile a python class `Honda` that takes another python class `Car` as input argument:

```
class Car(object):
    cc = '10'

class Honda(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.car = Car()

    def cal(self):
        'Do heavy calculations'
```

Numba can't identity the type of the type of python object (class) !

```
object = Car()
numba.typeof(object)      # Error (not numba type)
```

## Trial _ 1 (Not working)

```
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from numba import types, jit, njit

@jitclass([('car', types.pyobject)])  # I tried to add `nopython=False`, but raise error
class Honda(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.car = Car()
    
    @jit
    def cal(self):  # TypeError: class members are not yet supported
        'Do heavy calculations'
```

## Trial _ 2 (Not working)

```
@jitclass([('car', types.pyobject)])  # I tried to add `nopython=False`, but raise error
class Honda(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.car = typed.pyobject(Car())

    @jit
    def cal(self):  # TypeError: class members are not yet supported
        'Do heavy calculations'
```

## Trial _ 3 (Not working)

```
@jitclass() 
class Honda(object, Car):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @jit
    def cal(self):  # TypeError: class members are not yet supported
        'Do heavy calculations'
```

How can I simply use any python object (of any class type) inside a class that is compiled by a `numba.jitclass()` ? and add class members (@njit methods) to be used ?

Is there any better way to achieve this rather than a `numba.jitclass()` ?

Comment: How about making a separate function that does the heavy calculation (outside of the scope of the class), jit that, and then call it in the instance method?

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am trying to use separate functions

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a class in a jitclass, you need to make it a jitclass as well.

However:

```
@nb.experimental.jitclass
class Car0:
    cc = "10"
```

produces

```
TypeError: class members are not yet supported: cc
```

If you can live with an instance member instead of a class member, it will compile. For example:

```
@nb.experimental.jitclass
class Car:
    _cc: str

    def __init__(self, cc: str):
        self._cc = cc

    def cc(self) -> str:
        return self._cc + " cc"
```

Check:

```
>>> c = Car("10")
>>> c.cc()
'10 cc'
```

Then you can use it in the second class. Declaring its type is ugly, but it works:

```
car_type = nb.typeof(Car("10"))

@nb.experimental.jitclass
class Honda:
    car: car_type

    def __init__(self):
        self.car = Car("20")

    def cal(self) -> str:
        return self.car.cc()
```

Check:

```
>>> h = Honda()
>>> h.cal()
'20 cc'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, my setup is to work with classes